# PHP global array gives null inside function

Tags: php, arrays, function, global-variables

I receive the following error message when I attempt to call a function which I need to push an object into an array:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Any clues why this is happening? Thank you in advance :)

```
<?php
$programming = array();

//some unrelated lines of code here inbetween

function createProgramming($data){
        global $programming;
        $prog = new Programming($data);
        array_push($programming, $prog);
    }
?>

//random HTML here
<php?
createProgramming("str");
?>
//more html
```

$programming is only referenced in the code at those three locations present in my extract above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code works fine. There are few things that could make it break:

1. `$programming` is redefined / unset before `createProgramming()` is called
2. `$programming` is not defined in the global scope

Comment: $programming is only referred to at those three locations present in my example. The "$programming = array();" line is at the top of the document, the createProgramming function is defined a little bit further down, and then the createProgramming() is called upon even further down, in a small segment nestled inside the HTML content (passed to javascript via json).

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Have you tried running the OP's code? It **works** as a standalone file so something else must be breaking it. Either some of the unrelated code is tampering with `$programming` or `$programming = array()` isn't run in the global scope.